# Python get data from URL for all years dynamically

Tags: python

I have a link - https://www.boxofficemojo.com/year/2020/ ,

I'm able to convert to dataframes using pandas but I have to change the code for every year like for 2022 , 2021,2019,2018 and so on.
Is there any way where I can get all the available data without every time manually changing the year in url or re-writing the code for those years .

My code:

```
import pandas as pd

url_goal = 'https://www.boxofficemojo.com/year/2020/'
df_goal = pd.read_html(url_goal, index_col=0, header=0)[0]
df_goal
```

Please suggest a method where i can all the year's available data efficiently.

Thanks for the help!.

Comment: Use a loop and increment/decrement the number…?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this might be your best bet

```
url_goal = 'https://www.boxofficemojo.com/year/'
for i in range(first_year, last_year):
    url = url_goal + str(i) + '/'
    df_goal = pd.read_html(url, index_col=0, header=0)[0]
```